# Django {% trans %} not translating new changes

Tags: django, internationalization, django-translated-fields

I am trying to run a web-app locally (forked from [here](https://github.com/WikipediaLibrary/TWLight.git) ) . I am using the `{% trans %}` tag to mark strings to be translated.

The original piece of code was `<h3> Personal data</h3>`.

However , when I change it to `<h3>{% trans "Personal data" %}</h3>` , the "Personal data" does not get translated , even though the original text (from the forked repository) in the following line gets translated .

The following screenshot highlights the issue :
[image]

When I make any changes to the text between `<html>` tags, it gets reflected in my local instance. But when I make changes to strings marked with `{% trans %}` , it does not get translated in my local instance (even though the rest of the original text gets translated) .

Note : Changes made to text without `{% trans %}` tag are getting reflected in my local instance.
[image]

The app is run using `docker-compose up`

Why does the `{% trans %}` tag not work on new changes ?

Comment: You have to run `makemessages` and `compilemessages`. See [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#message-files)

Comment: @NKSM I ran `django-admin makemessages` and `django-admin compilemessages` . The changes are still not getting registered in the django.po file, and thus still not translating in the web app.